# How can I extract a 2D array that is stored in a JSON file?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have the following code that I am using to open the above json file and extract the data. However, I only want the coordinate data, but the code gives me the following error.
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

How would I print out just the coordinates data?

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        [
            -5.84731,
            60.5832
        ],
        [
            -5.93843,
            60.5832
        ],
        [
            -2.39097,
            60.5832
        ],
        [
            -2.39097,
            60.5843
        ],
        [
            -2.75097,
            60.5823
        ]
    ]
]
}



import json

f = open('allData.json')
data = json.load(f)
print(data['type']['coordinate'])

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
print(data['type']['coordinate'])
```

This is fetching `data['type']` first, = "Polygon", and then applying index `['coordinate']` to that, hence the error you're getting about indexing a string.

coordinates (plural) is not a child of type in your structure. You want `data['coordinates']`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the coordinates

```
import json

f = open('allData.json')
data = json.load(f)
print(data['coordinates'])
f.close()
```

Output

```
[[[-5.84731, 60.5832], [-5.93843, 60.5832], [-2.39097, 60.5832], [-2.39097, 60.5843], [-2.75097, 60.5823]]]
```